# PyQt and Threads: Multithreading inquiry

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, methodology

## The Situation

I am using `python 2.7`. I am working on an application that has a GUI utilizing `PyQt4`.

I have a button in a widget and when you click it it will request a range of IDs specified by the user. The user can specify how many threads the program should allocate for the "job".

### My Original Idea

The button spawns a job thread and passes it the range of IDs and the thread count. The job thread then can create child threads and pass them IDs from the range as necessary.

When all the IDs have been fetched the job thread can stop all its worker threads and then stop itself.

I would utilize signals / slots to update GUI elements with data as it is fetched by the worker threads within the job.

I am using threads so the GUI remains interact-able during the fetching process.

### The Problem

The "Dreaded PyQt Multi-threading Issue" occurred when I tried to spawn a thread from within a thread.

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
```

### My Workaround

I simply spawned the job thread and the worker threads from the widget that contains the button so no thread is spawned from within a thread, and then "connected" the worker threads to the job thread.

A la `aThread = ScrapeThread(self, aJob)` where aJob is the master Job thread.

This seems to work, but feels like a workaround more than the proper way to do this.

### The Question

What I did seems like a workaround rather than the proper way to multi-thread in PyQt.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll do that now. :)